# glm switches coefficient names for interactions

Tags: r, formula, glm, interaction, binomial-coefficients

I use the R code:

```
dat<-data.frame(p1=c(0,1,1,0,0), GAMMA.1=c(1,2,3,4,3), VAR1=c(2,2,1,3,4), GAMMA.2=c(1,1,3,4,1))
form <- p1 ~ GAMMA.1:VAR1 + GAMMA.2:VAR1
mod <- glm(formula=form, data=dat, family=binomial)
(coef <- coefficients(mod))

# (Intercept) GAMMA.1:VAR1 VAR1:GAMMA.2 
#   1.7974974   -0.2563667   -0.2181079
```

As we can see the names of `coef` for the interaction `GAMMA.2:VAR1` is not in the same order as in `form` (we have `VAR1:GAMMA.2` instead). For several reasons, I need the output

```
# (Intercept) GAMMA.1:VAR1   GAMMA.2:VAR1
#   1.7974974   -0.2563667   -0.2181079
```

without changing the names of the coefficients afterwards. Specifically, I want the same names for the coefficients as I used in the `form` object (without switching as in the code above). Can I tell `glm()` not to switch the names of the interactions?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, not without a lot of rewriting functions. The order of the label of interaction terms is determined by the `terms.formula` function, which itself is determined by the `termsform` function buried deep in the C code. There are no parameters that you can pass `termsform` that give you the behaviour that you want (although `keep.order` looked promising, it does not do what you want).

You would have to rewrite the `terms.formula` function to "swap back" the names after output from `termsform`, and then override the `terms.formula` function with your patched version, but are you sure you want that? It will be far easier to change the names of the coefficients afterwards.

---

You could also use `terms.formula` preemptively, and determine how your formula would be reordered, using and then create a mapping vector.

```
dat<-data.frame(p1=c(0,1,1,0,0), GAMMA.1=c(1,2,3,4,3), VAR1=c(2,2,1,3,4), GAMMA.2=c(1,1,3,4,1))
form <- p1 ~ GAMMA.1:VAR1 + GAMMA.2:VAR1
new.names<-labels(terms(form,data=dat,keep.order=TRUE))
names(new.names)<-as.character(form[[3]][-1])
new.names
# GAMMA.1:VAR1   GAMMA.2:VAR1 
# "GAMMA.1:VAR1" "VAR1:GAMMA.2"
```

You could use that vector to map names if you had the need later on.

Comment: More specifically the culprit is `stats:::C_termsform` (see [model.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/model.c), lines 970++).

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible workarounds for you.

One workaround comes from the observation that terms within interaction labels are ordered according to their order of appearance in the formula. In your example, the order is `GAMMA.1`, `VAR1`, `GAMMA.2`. You may be able to rewrite your formula with a different ordering so that the formula and coefficient names match:

```
form <- p1 ~ VAR1:GAMMA.1 + VAR1:GAMMA.2
mod <- glm(formula=form, data=dat, family=binomial)
coefficients(mod)

# (Intercept) VAR1:GAMMA.1 VAR1:GAMMA.2 
#   1.7974974   -0.2563667   -0.2181079
```

Another workaround is to rename the coefficients according to the formula when you pull them out:

```
rhs_terms <- c("(Intercept)",as.character(form[[3]][2:length(form[[3]])]))
(coef <- setNames(coefficients(mod), rhs_terms))

# (Intercept) GAMMA.1:VAR1 GAMMA.2:VAR1 
#   1.7974974   -0.2563667   -0.2181079
```